# how to undo "svn up -r<old version>"

Tags: svn

I wanted to go back and check how things looked at a previous commit, so I used

`svn up -r<number>`

As so many posts on this site suggest. But NOW I want to go BACK to what in git-speak is the HEAD, my most recent commit.

I checked svn log to get the revision number, but the log only goes up to the old commit I updated to.

How can I go back to my most recent revision? I'm a little scared to just

`svn revert`

Knowing that that has a tendency to destroy stuff if you're not careful.

Comment: The latest revision in the repository is also referred to as "HEAD" in SVN.  `revert` only undoes changes in your working copy, it doesn't touch the repository (on the server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A revert will not change the revision of your working copy, it will merely remove any changes that it contains. Just do an update without arguments:

```
svn update
```

The implicit revision is HEAD when you do not supply a revision number.  You could do it explicitly as well:

```
svn update -rHEAD
```

The update command will do its best to preserve your changes, while revert will remove them all.

Comment: So just to confirm then, if I don't want to keep my local changes (I was just poking around to remember how I did something before), then SVN revert will work too? i.e. it will take me back to HEAD (and kill my local changes?)

Comment: No, reverts do not change your revision (they don't even connect to the SVN repository, as a revert can be done by restoring the working copy from the cache of original files already hidden inside your working copy). To clear changes AND go back to HEAD you must do a revert then an update.